# Compiled with stack-based buffer overflow protection in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

One of the issues of **Android** and **iOS** applications is buffer overflow protection. Based on the security guidelines the mobile apps need to compiled with enabled stack-based buffer overflow protection (`-fstack-protector-all`). Is this flag necessary to be enabled in **Xamarin.Forms**? If yes, how to compile apps with the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms has nothing to do with the stack checks/canaries, it the Mono runtimes (and bundled support frameworks & shared libraries) that are provided by Xamarin.iOS (i.e. `Mono.framework/Mono`) and Xamarin.Android (i.e. `libmono-android.release.so` ) that are pre-compiled with stack checks/canaries, **PLUS** any 3rd-party native libs and user provided native libs that are bundled in the app.

## Examples:

Mono.framework/Mono

```
otool -Iv MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono | grep stack_chk
0x0014d508 33044 ___stack_chk_fail
0x001e4444 33045 ___stack_chk_guard
0x001e44d4 33044 ___stack_chk_fail
0x0014d554 33042 ___stack_chk_fail
0x001e4444 33043 ___stack_chk_guard
0x001e44cc 33042 ___stack_chk_fail
~~~
```

arm64-v8a/libmono-android.release.so

```
objdump -dj .text ./Xamarin/Android/lib/arm64-v8a/libmono-android.release.so | grep stack_chk
9130:   97fffd9c    bl  87a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
9254:   97fffd53    bl  87a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
98a0:   97fffbc0    bl  87a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
9a90:   97fffb44    bl  87a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
9cb0:   97fffabc    bl  87a0 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
~~~
```

Note: These are just sample outputs, it would be up to you to check ALL bundled native Frameworks/shared libraries in your app...